# Finding out where a file in the project explorer is used in the code in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing android applications using Eclipse IDE.

Now, I have given someone else's code to modify.
I need to check where a particular drawable/image in the res/drawable folder is used in the code or in the xml (res/layout). Also I need to find where I a particular xml (res/layout file) is used in the code. 
Is there any short-cut to find out these things or I need to go through each & every line of code to find out these things ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ankit
For First Thing for checking a particular drawable/image in the res/drawable folder  if you want to find that whether image resource is used in project or not for that you have to search like this in Eclipse For Example Your image name is bg.png so you can search like this using Ctrl+h in your Project Explorer than when search window Open you will find one File Search tab than write this in search box @drawable/bg than you will get Match Result.

For Second Thing Now use Same Ctrl+h than write this R.layout.yourlayoutname  in search box than if this layout is used in your android project than you will get result for that.